# Нужно ли ставить плагин кэширования на WordPress, работающий на PHP 7?

Tags: wordpress, кэширование, wordpress-плагины, php7

Возник спорный вопрос, ставить плагин кэширования на WordPress или нет? Раньше всегда использовал, но, с появлением php 7, мне дали совет удалить плагин, т.к. он может, наоборот, привести к потере скорости загрузки.

Может быть, кто-то уже проводил эксперименты и знает наверняка. Подскажите, пожалуйста, ставить или лучше не ставить?

Спасибо.

Comment: Для начала стоит узнать какие кеши вообще бывают.. и НЕ СТАВИТЬ кеш плагины без понимания что и как КОНКРЕТНЫЙ плагин будет делать на КОНКРЕТНОМ сервере.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такие советы - уверенное проявление некомпетентности.

Что происходит при обращении к закешированной странице?

- Веб-сервер (nginx или apache) принимает запрос, видит, что надо обратиться к index.php
- Веб-сервер запускает php-fpm (что не быстро совсем)
- WordPress начинает работу
- В самом начале загрузки встревает кеширующий плагин и подсовывает готовый .html вместо бесконечно долгой (в этих временных терминах) генерации страницы

Никогда полная генерация страницы не будет быстрее подсовывания готового .html. Хоть десятый php поставьте. Да, php7 быстрее в два-три раза по тестам, чем php5, но кеш обогнать невозможно.

Почитайте мою статью о том, как настроить WordPress с кешированием на успешную обработку [10,000 обращений в секунду](https://kagg.eu/10000-clients-second-wordpress/).

Обратите внимание на результаты. Если совсем кратко, то обращение к странице весом в 1.6МБ:

- без кеширования - 100 обращений в секунду
- с WP Super Cache - 1,000 обращений в секунду
- с микрокешированием nginx - 3,000 обращений в секунду
- с использованием подготовленных WP Super Cache файлов .html, но напрямую из nginx - 7,500 обращений в секунду

Обращение к маленькой странице типа Контактов:
 - с использованием подготовленных WP Super Cache файлов .html, но напрямую из nginx - 10,000 обращений в секунду

Comment: Вот только согласен только с первым предложением. Остальное же - бесцельный сферический конь в вакууме. Просто потому что нет одного универсального рецепта. Всё зависит и от сайта и от компонентов и от севера.

Comment: @SeVlad сервер, сайт и компоненты описаны в статье по ссылке.

Comment: Ятття умоляю.. Кто там будет что читать.. да и толку. Без понимания кеширования вообще и ВПшного  в частности. Всё бестолку..

Comment: @SeVlad ну, худо-бедно 1250 просмотров + пара комментов статья имеет ))

Comment: ооох.. :) в слаке написал